# No matching function for 'pow'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double ans;

    cout << endl << "Enter a";
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl << "Enter b:";
    cin >> b;

    ans = pow(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)), 0.5)

    cout << ans << endl;
```

In the line where I am assigning `ans` it says "no matching function for 'pow'.

Comment: You have 3 '(' and 4 ')'. Its a typo.. Also your missing a semicolon.

Comment: FYI, multiplication (x * x) is more efficient than `pow(x,2)`.  Also, `pow` is a floating point function and may produce conversion inaccuracies when used with integers.  Some compilers may recognize the `pow(x,2)` pattern and replace with `x * x`, at higher optimization levels.

Answer (score 3):

### The statement in question is malformed.

Your opening and closing parenthesis are unbalanced.  The outer call to `pow()` is trying to call it with only 1 input parameter, hence the compiler error since `pow()` takes 2 parameters.

But, even if it did happen to compile (say, there was a 1-param overload in scope somewhere), then the result of that outer `pow()` would just be ignored, the result of the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) would be assigned to `ans` instead - if that even compiled, which it won't since you would then have an erroneous closing parenthesis after the `0.5`, and a missing semicolon at the end of the statement.

You need to change that line to this instead:

`ans = pow(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2), 0.5);`

Comment: Wow thanks, I was basing the C++ code from a python file that was meant to do the same thing. It is supposed to solve all the 8th-grade math homework. Again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

ans = pow(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2), 0.5);

You had an extra ")" after 2 and  your line was missing a semicolon.